# How to add a Appbar to my code, i have tried so many tutorials and i cannot stitch the code code together

Tags: flutter

I have tried to use the basic AppBar Demo code and add it to my code but for the life of me i cannot get it to work.

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddTwoNumbers> createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  List<TextEditingController> roundOneFields = [];
  List<TextEditingController> roundTwoFields = [];
  int roundOneResult = 0;
  int roundTwoResult = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    roundOneFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    roundTwoFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R1 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundOneFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 24,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundTwoFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                          roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                      roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                          roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried the below code but could not get it to work with my code above, im missing some like a Scaffold or containing the code. Also what concept am i missing here for my own sake and to help others.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know you made mistake while posting the question or I am reading it in different manner but it seems like you are calling the main function twice which you are not allowed to do,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddTwoNumbers> createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  List<TextEditingController> roundOneFields = [];
  List<TextEditingController> roundTwoFields = [];
  int roundOneResult = 0;
  int roundTwoResult = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    roundOneFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    roundTwoFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('This is title for AppBar')), // This is how you can add an appBar.
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R1 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundOneFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 24,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundTwoFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                          roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                      roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                          roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Remove all the code from your editor and just try copy pasting this code, it will do what you are trying to achieve.

[image: This code will generate this output]

Comment: Thanks So much, Ahmad, but i pasted the code in and got a few errors some where missing the ending } -----  but the main error was around the "body" statement:
The named parameter 'body' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'body'.
But much appreaciated for your help

Comment: The error you are saying will occur only in once case if you have not imported the material class `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` , and if you have imported the material class and still getting this issue then maybe you have done something wrong during setup of flutter. or you can just try typing this import line manually, sometimes flutter fails to recognize the import if it is copy pasted.

Comment: I modified the code a bit and added the output I am getting through that code, Check original answer I have updated it.

Comment: O thank you so much Ahmad Ali, and to all the other contributers Its working now as expected. I have learnt so much from you guys. respect...

Answer (score 4):

`Scaffold` provides `appBar`. you can use it.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('this one is title'),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering the question so Quickly, but i tried to add it after the below like this but had many errors "Where do i add it", what part of my code above thanks Yeasin

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
{ Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('this one is title'),
  ),}
void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

Comment: it will be inside your `AddTwoNumbers` and inside the build method where you are returning `Scaffold`

Answer (score 1):

`Scaffold` has a property `appbar` like other property `body`, `floatingActionButton`, `backgroundColor`. Usually, we use `appbar` to achieve AppBar. (Alternatively, we can make custom appbar also)

**This example is for `Scaffold` with `appbar`.**

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("This is appbar title"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
        ),
        Text(
          '10',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: HI Ashikul, Sorry what did you add to the conversation, did you change some code?

Comment: I just share the way, how you can achieve an AppBar inside Scaffold widget. Sometimes we can't achieve perfect results using the Scaffold AppBar widget. 
That time we can make our own custom appBar widget with a few changes.